# ImportError with importing keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to import keras it gives me an error `from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops`.

```
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/kerasenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/kerasenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/kerasenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
ImportError: cannot import name tensor_array_ops
```

I really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Which versions are you using? Python, keras and tf

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is not showing the keras version by this command `python -c "import keras; print keras.__version__"` . it is showing the same error, but python version is Python 2.7.13. It should be the latest version of keras which is `keras-1.2.2`.

Comment: How about tensorflow?

Comment: when I am trying to check the tensorflow version by this command  `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` , it is giving error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: How did you install TF?

Comment: I was following the command from this [link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-python-deep-learning-library-keras/) . Indeed, that is the first time I am installing keras. Thanks

Comment: This is just installing keras... you need to install a backend. Choose Tensorflow or Theano.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `sudo pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

You may be using an older version of TensorFlow.