# Importing Keras causes "Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations" error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, keras

Im runnign a machine on Google cloud `(16 vCPUs, 41 GB memory) CPU platform Intel Skylake` which im running `keras` on it, im getting the following error:

```
yehoshaphat_schellekens@try-kaggle-toxic:~/toxic$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:26:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib as contrib
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import learn
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io.dask_io import *
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/dask_io.py", line 23, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .. import array as da
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/array/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core import (Array, stack, concatenate, take, tensordot, transpose,
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 13, in <module>
    from toolz.curried import (pipe, partition, concat, unique, pluck, join, first,
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _curry_namespace(vars(toolz)),
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 48, in _curry_namespace
    for name, f in ns.items() if '__' not in name
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    for name, f in ns.items() if '__' not in name
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 42, in _should_curry
    return (callable(f) and _nargs(f) > 1 or f in do_curry)
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 35, in _nargs
    return len(inspect.getargspec(f).args)
  File "/home/yehoshaphat_schellekens/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 1050, in getargspec
    raise ValueError("Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations"
ValueError: Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, use getfullargspec() API which can support them
```

Ive tried solutions from here: [ImportError with importing keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556972/importerror-with-importing-keras) (like upgrading `tensoreflow`) or from here: [Getting ImportError while importing keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374447/getting-importerror-while-importing-keras) but they both seem to solve a different problem.

Notice that i have `tensoreflow' installed:

```
yehoshaphat_schellekens@try-kaggle-toxic:~$ sudo python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.4.1
```

Any help on that (or at least an explanation on what is a *Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations* would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does importing tensorflow directly in a python shell works without erroring?

Comment: Yes, see my update

Comment: do you have multiple Keras versions installed? what does "conda list" in your environment and "pip list" tell you?

Comment: I tried the following on Intel Skylake:
1) Created a conda virtual environment with same python version as yours i.e. 3.5.4.
2) Installed tensorflow and Keras
3) Ran python interpreter 4) Ran import Keras I am not getting any error.
One thing I observed that in your snapshot there is Anaconda custom while mine is showing Anaconda, Inc.
Is it possible to share the steps that you followed for this installation?